# Why do I keep getting 0x80070005 when updating Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, I keep getting error 0x80070005 whenever I try to apply an update or add a Windows feature, which is `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

When I try to monitor with Process Monitor, I see `FSCTL_SET_EXTERNAL_BACKING` on some files in `\Windows\Servicing\Sessions\*.xml` is failing with `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`, which is confusing. Messing with permissions doesn't help.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The hint is logged in `\Windows\Servicing\Sessions\CBS.log`:

```
Info  CBS  Failed WOF compressing file \\?\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\Sessions\{name}.xml
```

WOF refers to the Windows Overlay File System, used for file compression in Windows 10.

Turning CompactOS off (via runnin `Compact /CompactOS:Never` in the Command Prompt) makes the error go away. (It's not clear to me why the problem even exists, though.)